# compare two .csv files using awk\ unix

Tags: shell, unix, csv, awk

file1:

```
SA, 5006, 12, , DJ
CN, BN, , BBB, 13
22, 67, GG, FF, 88
33, BB, AA, CC, 22
```

file2:

```
SA, 5006, 12, 15 , DJ
CN, BN, , BBB, 13
empty line
33, CC, AA, dd, 22
```

output:

```
SA, 5006, 12, 15 , DJ, unmatch, 4
CN, BN, , BBB, 13, match
empt, empt, empt, empt, empt, unmatch, 12345
33, CC, AA, dd, 22, unmatch, 24
```

I need to compare two .csv files line by line, but some of field/lines can be empty and output should be in file3:
5 columns form file 2, match\unmatch, unmatch Fields like this:

```
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, match/unmatch, concatenation of digits representing unmatch fields.
```

I try something but I new with awk can anyone help? :)

code that I use, but I think the problem its empty fields anf I dont know How I can print the :

```
 ##Set input and output field separators to ':'.
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ":"
}


NR == FNR {
    ## save all the line in an array, so lines will be saved like:
    ## c1::c2::c3::c4::c5

    ++a[$0]

    ## Process next line from the beginning.
    next
}

## for every line of second file.
{ 

    ## Search for the line in the array, if not exists it means that any field is     different  
    ## print the line.
    if ( !a[$0] ) {
            $6 = "same"
            print
    }else {
   $6 = " not same"
            print
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt the output of output for last line be just `... unmatch, 2` instead of `24`?

Comment: Why are you setting the field separator to `:` when the file uses `,`?

Comment: Hi @jaypal

IT should be 24 look again (:

Comment: @YifatKatrielUdi The output is still wrong even so. It should be `dd` in the output and not `CC`? Should the output contain lines from file1 or file2?

Comment: @jaypal, yes! my mistake (: you right

Comment: @jaypal you delete your answer?

Comment: @YifatKatrielUdi Yes, didn't Barmar's solution work out for you?

Comment: I ask, because I new in stuckoverflow (: and I want to undserstan

Comment: @jaypal actually I use your answer, but I have problem . when I have two empty line in both files it's write unmatched I paste your code:

Comment: @jaypal your code: BEGIN { FS = OFS = ", " }
NR==FNR { line[NR] = $0; nf[NR] = NF; next }
NF{
    if ( line[FNR] == $0 ) {
        print $0, "match";
        next
    }
    else {
        split (line[FNR], col, FS);
        flds = ""
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i != col[i]) {
                flds = flds i
            }
        } 
        print $0, "unmatch", flds
    }
    next
}
{
    flds = ""
    for(i=1; i<=nf[FNR]; i++) {
        flds = flds i
        printf "%s%s", "empt", FS
    }
    print "unmatch", flds
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the line number as the index of the array that you save between files, so you can compare corresponding lines in the two files.

```
BEGIN { FS = ", "; }
NR == FNR { a[FNR] = $0 } # In first file, just save each line in an array
NR != FNR { if (a[FNR] == $0) { # Compare line in 2nd file to corresponding line in first file
                $6 = "match";
            } else {
                $6 = "unmatch";
                split(a[FNR], b); # Split up the fields from the first file
                $7 = ""
                for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { # Compare each field
                    if ($i != b[i]) { $7 = $7 i; } # Add non-matching field numbers to output
                }
            }
            print;
        }
```

Comment: That was fast!
Thanks @barmar 
I would be very happy if you can put notes, so I could learn from it, If it's not hard :)

Comment: I've added comments, are they helpful?

Comment: Ok (: i, see, I dont understand, yesterday I see 2  answer, and today only one, why?

Comment: first the match/unmatched appear in field 5 and not in sperate field, second if I have two Line empty in parallel it's appear unmatched /:

Comment: The author of the other answer deleted it yesterday.

Comment: I had a couple of typos yesterday, I've fixed them now and tested it.